# walk up the stairs in twos and threes

Tags: vocabulary

Does that mean there are groups of two or three ghosts walking up the stairs? Or that ghosts are walking up two or three stairs at a time?

> She shouldn’t have been surprised if there was an endless parade of
>   ghosts traipsing through the house and the acre of grass and garden
>   outside.  **Ghosts walking up the carpeted stairs in twos and
>   threes**, ghosts staring out a window that is no longer there, ghosts
>   wedged up in the breakfast nook sitting in front of invisible tea
>   sets.

Comment: Ghosts. Why do you say people? They are not referred to. Because they are walking?

Comment: Oh, I'll correct it. The focus was not this, wether it's people or ghosts who are walking. I want to know if it's three or four ghosts walking, or one ghost walking two or three steps at a time.

Comment: I've always thought that ghosts do not walk. They float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that an unstated number of groups of ghosts were walking up the stairs, with each group containing 2 or 3 ghosts side by side eachother, taking presumably 1 step at a time, since that's the normal way to walk up the stairs. If they weren't walking up the normal way, then the author would have stated that the ghosts were skipping 1 to 2 stairs as they walked up with each stride.